# How to post data from google books API to your Book model using Django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, google-books

I know this is my first question and I wouldn't be like writing it here, but I have a problem which I couldn't handle for 2 days now.

I am writing an app in Django, and my goal is to handle requests from google books API and display books in the template which I did.
I wrote a function like this

> services.py

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import json


def get_books_data(query):
    """Retriving data from google books API"""

    service = build('books', 
                    'v1', 
                    developerKey=API_KEY
                    )
    request = service.volumes().list(q=query)
    response = request.execute()
    book_list = [response['items'][item]['volumeInfo']
                 for item in range(len(response['items']))]

    return book_list
```

I get a list of key: value pairs representing ten books from API.

I passed them into a template like this

> views.py

```
def search(request):

query = request.GET.get('q')
books = get_books_data(query)
context = {

    'books': books
}

return render(request, 'books_list.html', context)
```

This is how book_list.html looks like.

> list_book.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content%}
  {% for book in books %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <ul class="list-group shadow">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
              <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
                <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">{{ book.title }}</h5>
                <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">{{ book.subtitle }}</p>
                {% for identifier in book.industryIdentifiers %}
                  <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">{{ identifier.type }} : {{ identifier.identifier }}</p>
                {% endfor  %}
                <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">Language: {{ book.language }}</p>
                <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">Published date: {{ book.publishedDate }}</p>
                <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
                {% if book.authors %}
                <h6 class="font-weight-bold my-2">Authors:</h6>
                {% for author in book.authors %}
                  <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small">{{ author }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% if book.pageCount %}
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-1">
                  <h6 class="font-weight-bold my-2">Number of pages: {{book.pageCount}}</h6>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              {% if book.imageLinks %}
                <img class="thumbnail" src="{{book.imageLinks.thumbnail}}" alt="">
              {% else %}
                <img class="thumbnail2" src="{% static 'images/placeholder4.png'%}" alt="">
              {% endif %}
            </div>
            <form action="." method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD THIS BOOK TO YOUR BOOKSHELF</button>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And last part of my task is to have a button in each card with a book, I can use to save a particular book from API to the database.
I am a beginner in Django, and I've tried to use forms, I've read, I could use Django Rest Framework somehow but really, I don't have an idea, how I could approach this problem.

Please, Can you help me?

Than you in advance.

Comment: You need a way to deserialize JSON data you receive from google's API, so it could be then used for creating new model instances. Django has serializer function that you can use, or you can use Django REST as a more advanced tool for working with APIs, but it's still very approachable and much like pure Django. It's 100% worth learning. Here is the link to read about Django's serializer function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/